# Ubuntu 18.04 Uncompression error -- system halted

Tags: 18.04

Ubuntu 18.04  system dont want to start  it gives uncompression error -- system halted
and keep showing the some screen no other options
[image: bootscreen]

Comment: That might be a problem with your RAM, or with the  motherboard of your computer. It could be a problem with the contact points. Removing the RAM and sticking it back in could possibly help.

Comment: thank you so much @vanadium so tha men i have to open my laptop right ?  else i have two hard disk on my laptop one for windows and the second for ubunto windows when i start work normal but when i boot on ubunto gives me this error by the way it was everything good untill this morning when i turned on my laptop thats happend

Comment: Might also be a problem with the drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much vanduim for your intervention.
i wanna inform you that i fixed this problem by booting using a flash memory contains the ubunto setup and repaired the messed files and then restart my os  finally  worked find hope this solution help others too

Answer (score 0):

estoy presentando el mismo problema, me gustaría saber cómo hizo para  arrancar usando una memoria flash que contiene la configuración ?

A mí no me permite hacer nada , conecto un USB boot y no pasa del menú del sistema boot y vuelve a dar el mismo error

Por favor ayuda

Comment: write your answer in english please